# Can you use Ethereum wallet to receive/send tokens of layer 2 blockchains?

Tags: wallets, polygon, layer-2

If I create a wallet for Ethereum blockchain, can I use the same wallet (and accounts) for layer 2  Ethereum based blockchains (like Polygon and MATIC coin) as well?

Side note: I've created a wallet using [python-hdwallet](https://github.com/meherett/python-hdwallet) and loaded that wallet to MetaMask. But I want to be sure if I can safely use this wallet for Polygon (and any other Ethereum based blockchain/currency as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum private keys and accounts (addresses) are the same across different Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) based blockchains. You can make a wallet work in another network by simply switching the Web3 provider to point to a different JSON-RPC endpoint. All JSON-RPC providers have copied the original Ethereum API.

(Note: Rootstock RSK is a notable difference as they are using a different checksum method)

Comment: Your first sentence ends with "... accross different blockchains". Does that mean ethereum wallets also work for blockchains that are not related to ethereum?

Comment: Very good comment. I edited the answer and clarified.